# Кроссплатформенное графическое приложение

Tags: windows, кроссплатформенность, linux

Насколько реально и как написать графическое приложение работающее на Linux ( + Android) и Win ? Как в данном случае себя QT проявит ?

Comment: Qt под андроид не подойдет. В вашем случае лучше использовать Java

Comment: Для Linus<->Win Qt - отличное решение. Но с андроидом сложности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблему надо рассматривать в контексте кросс-платформенностьи на телефоне и десктопе.

Для дескотопов отдельно существуют кросс-платформенные решения - да тот же Java Swing. Для мобильных платформ также есть кросс-платформенные решения: самая известная это [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - покрывает Android, iOS, J2ME, BlackBerry и Symbian

А вот и чтобы десктоп и мобильная платформа в одном флаконе - таких решений я не видел (ну кроме Qt). Оно в общем то неудивительно поскольку слишком уже отличаются интерфейсы на десктопах и мобильных платформах.

Answer (score 2):

1. Под Windows/Linux - Qt работает вполне прилично, особенно если не использовать каких-то специфических для ОС вещей, вроде обращений к устройствам и т.п.
2. Android в силу мобильности отличается от вышеупомянутых ОС, и под него Qt не пойдет, аналогом Qt здесь будет что-нибудь вроде Rhodes.

Вообще обычно делают так: разбивают приложение на уровни (интерфейс - логика - устройства) и то, что можно делают кроссплатформенно (например, логика вполне пишется на C/C++ и компилируется под нужную ОС), а все остальное - делают по отдельности для каждой ОС.